# append array and ArrayList to ArrayList

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Using Jenkins pipeline we have our own build script. Also all of our projects have a rakefile which is what we use to do a lot of the building steps. Our typical jenkins build executes 3 rake tasks but we do have some exceptions and that has to do when we have a angular website we try to build with it.

I've configured my pipeline like this:

```
buildGitProject {
    repository='https://anonymous.visualstudio.com/Project/_git/my-csharp-project-with-angular'
    branchName= 'master'
    solutionName='MyCSharpSolution.sln'
    emailTo='someone@aol.com'
    preRakeCommands=['install_npm_dependencies', 'ng_build']
}
```

that relies on our build script which is this:

```
def call(body) {
    def args= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = args
    body()

    def agentName = "windows && ${args.branchName}"
    def remoteConfig = org.pg.RemoteConfigFactory.create(args.repository);

    pipeline {
        agent none
        options {
            buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: org.pg.Settings.BUILDS_TO_KEEP))
            skipStagesAfterUnstable()
            timestamps()
        }
        stages {
            stage("checkout") {
                agent any
                steps {
                    checkoutFromGit(remoteConfig, args.branchName)
                }
            }
            stage('build') {
                agent{node{ label agentName as String}}
                steps {
                    buildSolution(args.solutionName, args.get('preRakeCommands', []), args.get('postRakeCommands', []))
                }
            }
            stage('test') {
                agent{node{ label agentName as String}}
                steps {
                    testSolution(args.solutionName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which fails in the build stage. 
**buildSolution.groovy**

```
def call(String solutionName, ArrayList preRakeCommands, ArrayList postRakeCommands) {
    unstash 'ws'
    String[] rakeCommands = [
        "build_solution[${solutionName}, Release, Any CPU]",
        "copy_to_deployment_folder",
        "execute_dev_dropkick"
    ]
    String[] combinedRakeCommand = (preRakeCommands.plus(rakeCommands).plus(postRakeCommands)) as String[]
    executeRake( combinedRakeCommand )
    stash name: 'deployment', includes: 'deployment/**/*'
}
```

**executeRake.groovy**

```
def call(String... rakeTasks) {
    def safeRakeTasks = rakeTasks.collect{ "\"$it\"" }.join(' ');
    bat script: "rake ${safeRakeTasks}"
}
```

in the jenkins build log it says:

```
08:43:09 C:\jenkins_repos\Project\my-csharp-project-with-angular>rake "install_npm_dependencies" "ng_build" "[Ljava.lang.String;@11bd466"
```

I have no idea how or why it is using a string pointer because I thought that `plus` concated arrays and ArrayList... Plus it is in Jenkins so it is a pain to test.

Comment: fixed it.. silly me. I should have used `ArrayList.addAll`. Silly C# habbits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List a = ['a1','a2','a3']
String [] s = ['s1','s2','s3']
List b = ['b1','b2','b3']

println a.plus(s as List).plus(b)
```

output:

```
[a1, a2, a3, s1, s2, s3, b1, b2, b3]
```

Comment: i used a slightly different approach but this one would have worked too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
List a = ['a1','a2','a3']
String[] s = ['s1','s2','s3']
List b = ['b1','b2','b3']

println ([*a,*s,*b])
```

alternatively

```
println a + [*s] + b
```

which should perform better